# How to find all files that contain the + sign on a directory recursively?

Tags: search, file-search

I have tried many suggestions but nothing worked. I have to find all files containing + signs anywhere on the name, like:

- Hello + World.jpg
- A + good + file + name + to + find.png

**Using Ubuntu 16.04 x64**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be any more complicated than `find path/to/directory/ -name '*+*'`

Ex.

```
$ find . -name '*+*'
./foo/list89988777,,,,,+--.txt
./foo/+
./dir/A + good + file + name + to + find.png
```

Add `-type f` if you want to limit the results to only regular files.

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm.